# How to get correct rendering for \dh \TH (ð þ Þ)?

Tags: symbols, pdftex, rendering

I have some references containing \dh and \TH. When using these symbols in either the LaTeX source or the .bib file I only get a black box. Neither \dh nor ð works. According to the documentation, T1 only is needed which is what I already use.

.tex and .bib files use utf8 without BOM as encoding. Here's a short example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,german]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{scrhack}%ignore Warning float@addtolist
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage{aecompl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{autofe}%(not working) bugfix: \dh und \TH
%\PrerenderUnicode{\dh\TH}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{relsize}

\begin{document}
\dh \TH Þ ð þ
\end{document}
```

What is needed to render these Letters correctly?

Comment: the package ae is obsolete and should not be used any-more. Maybe this is causing you some trouble/package conflicts

Comment: @Martin H: that was exactly it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

do not load `ae` and `aecompl`! Use

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,german]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
...
```